# Dependencies unmet Mysql-server Mysql-client Linux

Tags: mysql, debian

I am almost a week with this issue, had reinstall the system and use to install mysql-server mysql-client as the first to evade a possibly conflict within other apps.

Followed a lot of tutorials but no one results

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzESD.png)

I executed it as root and have the lastest Parrot

apt-get update tells me that i have no more new updates.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1291372/what-is-the-step-by-step-procedure-to-fix-the-the-following-packages-have-unmet) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant install Mysql.

But insted i find MariaDB, that is totally compatible with my distro.
Is has all the same utilities than Mysql and comes included in some other distros al default.